# The lightest (most lightweight) Google Drive REST API query/response?

Tags: google-drive-api, google-drive-android-api

When initializing the [REST Google Drive API](https://developers.google.com/drive/web/about-sdk) in an Android app, I need to 'poke' the server to produce the

> UserRecoverableAuthIOException

In order to minimize the network traffic, I'm searching for the most 'lightweight' request that would produce such an exception. Currently, I use the following construct:

```
com.google.api.services.drive.Drive svc;
svc.files().get("root").setFields("title").execute();
```

basically pulling the 'root' name.

Is this the lowest amount of traffic that would do the job?

Comment: Why do you need to do that?  Can't you just use GoogleAuthUtil to request a token?  Or, just display this the first time you make a real request?

Comment: @CherylSimon Thanks, didn't think about it this way, The idea developed from originally catching every execute's  'UserRecoverableAuthIOException' (as you suggest). I was cleaning some code trying to align it with GDAA's 'connect()'.

Comment: Ah, yeah, so its theoretically possible for any call to through that exception, but once you've gotten an oauth token once, it would only ever happen again if the user manually revoked auth, which is pretty unlikely.  I think you can just request ouath at a convenient time, and then handle the rest of them less prettily.

Comment: Speaking, of 'user revoking auth', I'm just working on another issue - coming soon :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The amount of traffic that is generating is negligible.
It won't count as much at all.

Unless it's for academic purposes you won't achieve anything more from further optimizing for speed. There's a point where it stops being a bottleneck.

So yes that is quite likely the lightest way you can generate the UserRecoverableAuthIOException

Comment: Thanks, I was 'kind of' aware of that. I was just curious if there is a special 'poke' trick only [these guys](https://youtu.be/r2dr8_Mxr2M) would know :-)